# How to update UITableViewCells using NSTimer and NSNotificationCentre in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nstimer, nsnotificationcenter

NOTE: Asking for answers in **Swift** please.

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Have tableview cells update every 1 second and display a real-time
  countdown.

**How I'm doing it currently:**

- I have a tableview with cells that contain a label.
- When the cells are generated, they call a function that calculates the time between today and a stored target date, and it displays the countdown time remaining in the label.
- To get the cells to update the label every second, I
  use an `NSTimer` that reloads the tableview every second.
- **PROBLEM:** The countdown works, but when I try to do a Swipe-to-Delete action, because the `NSTimer` reloads the tableview, it resets the
  swiped cell so that it is no longer swiped and of course this is not acceptable for end users.

**What I'm trying / Potential Solutions**

- I heard that a better way to do this is to use `NSNotificationCenter` that is triggered by `NSTimer` and add listeners to each cell. Every 1 second a "broadcast" is sent from the `NSNotificationCenter`, the cell will receive the "broadcast" and will update the label.
- I tried adding a listener to each cell in the part of the code where it generates a new cell:

  ```
  // Generate the cells

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tablecell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
  let countdownEntry = fetchedResultController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CountdownEntry

  // MARK: addObserver to "listen" for broadcasts
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateCountdownLabel", name: mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil)

  func updateCountdownLabel() {
      println("broadcast received in cell")
      if let actualLabelCountdown = labelCountdown {
          // calculate time between stored date to today's date
          var countdownValue = CountdownEngine.timeBetweenDatesRealTime(countdownEntry.date)
          actualLabelCountdown.text = countdownValue
      }
  }
  ```
- but the observer's selector only seems to be able to target functions at the view controller level, not in the cell. (I can't get "updateCountdownLabel" to fire from within the cell. When I create a function of the same name at view controller level, the function can be called)

**Questions**

- So my question is: Is this is the right approach?
- If yes, how can I get the listener to fire a function at the cell level?
- If no, then what is the best way to achieve this real-time countdown without interrupting Swipe on Cell actions?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [AnyObject], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)` instead of `reloadData`?

Comment: this is how I used to reload the table cells  `func timerAction() {
        // update the countdown label with the countdown value
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }` Would using "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths" avoid cancelling out a swipe state for the cell? And where would I call "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths" if I was to use it in this scenario?

Comment: You could avoid the swiped cell in your list of index paths. If you have access to the label directly to update the countdown value, you don't need to call `reload` at all.

Comment: Great. So with this method would NSTimer's selector target a function that uses "reloadRowsAtIndexPaths" that also has a condition: if swiped, don't reload? Also, does NSNotificationCentre still play a role or should it be discarded?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might be a solution not reloading cells at all. Just make the cells listen to an update notification and change their label accordingly.
I assume you subclass `UITableViewCell` and give the cell a `storedDate` property. You will set that property when preparing the cell.

The timer will just fire the notification.

Remember to unregister the cell from notification center in `dealloc`

Here is a quick an dirty example.

The View Controller containing your TableView:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var timer: NSTimer!


    //MARK: UI Updates

    func fireCellsUpdate() {
        let notification = NSNotification(name: "CustomCellUpdate", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notification)
    }

    //MARK: UITableView Data Source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "CustomCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as! CustomTableViewCell
        cell.timeInterval = 20
        return cell
    }

    //MARK: View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("fireCellsUpdate"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(self.timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    }


    deinit {
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }

}
```

The custom cell subclass:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var timeInterval: NSTimeInterval = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.label.text = "\(timeInterval)"
        }
    }

    //MARK: UI Updates

    func updateUI() {
        if self.timeInterval > 0 {
            --self.timeInterval
        }
    }

    //MARK: Lifecycle

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: Selector("updateUI"), name: "CustomCellUpdate", object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

}
```

I'm pretty sure this example doesn't adhere to your app's logic. Just showing how things are *glowed* together.

Comment: This was what I was trying to do, but I'm not sure if I'm assigning the listener to the cell properly. `// MARK: addObserver to "listen" for broadcasts`
`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateCountdownLabel", name: mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil)` I'm using Core Data to store the dates and yes, I give the cell a property for that date. The listener successfully receives the notification, but I don't know how to target a function inside the cell to update the date label. The selector can only target functions at ViewController level...

Comment: When a listener receives the notification-- where should I put the function the selector targets? In the cell or at the view controller level?

Comment: thanks! I am still pretty new to Swift so the sample code really helps. I will attempt this later tonight and post back my results.

Comment: when I changed to custom cells, I was no longer able to access Core Data. Could use your help here if possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653764/storing-retrieving-core-data-in-custom-cell-in-swift Thanks!

Comment: a lot of things changed in Swift 4 but it still works :)

Comment: @J.Doe really nice it can still give some help :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Ian MacDonald has suggested you should avoid reloading the cell when the timer ticks, if you are swiping. Also drop the NSNotification, as It and timer are essentially doing the samething

Comment: If I drop `NSNotification` and strictly use `NSTimer` to update the cells, then I assume the `NSTimer` calls a function that loops through each cell and updates it's label?